# How do I run a saved html from jsfiddle locally?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I'm trying to run a jsfiddle code locally, specifically this one:
http://jsfiddle.net/BAqTe/

I've looked around and people suggest using "/show" and saving the page, and loading the dependencies, but it doesn't work locally for me.I have jquery.1.8.3 and I have included it.The "onYouTubeIframeAPIReady" however never gets called.What do I need to run it locally?This is the code I have so far.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[ 

$(window).load(function(){
// Add the API 
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
// Register the player
var player;
onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
   player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {     
                  events: {
         'onReady': onPlayerReady,
'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                          }
                         });
                        }

 // Add some controls (they can't be called before onPlayerReady in real life)
 $('#play').click(function() {    
   player.playVideo();
 });
 $('#pause').click(function() {  
   player.pauseVideo();
 });
 });
 //]]>  
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <iframe class="video-frame" id="ytplayer" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/RP4abiHdQpc?controls=0&showinfo=0&enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
 <button id="play">Play</button>
 <button id="pause">Pause</button>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: The problem is probably indicated in the error message(s) - also make sure to look for non-OK responses in the network activity. For starters, I would use external CDNs to load standard libraries such as jQuery.

Comment: @user2246674: What error messages are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

```js
onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
   player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {     
                  events: {
         'onReady': onPlayerReady,
'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                          }
                         });
                        }
```

`onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` is likely being called, but there are errors, as `onPlayerReady` and `onPlayerStateChange` are not defined as functions.

Either copy the two missing functions from your jsfiddle, or don't include them as events.

Comment: Yeah the code has those functions, that is not the problem.I have those functions.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady is never called.What could be the issue?

Comment: Can you update your code to show the two functions mentioned? Other than that... I have small doubt about `tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";` missing 'https:'. Is there `<script src="https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-widgetapi-vflXiNhG3.js" async=""></script>` being added into `<head>`?